# Fixing a button at the bottom of a Constraint Layout

Tags: xml, android-studio, button, layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to fix a button at the bottom of a Constraint Layout. There are solutions to this but they are all in Relative Layout. Is it possible to fix the button at the bottom in a Constraint Layout only?

I tried using Vertical/Horizontal Bias but it did not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To fix a button at the bottom of a ConstraintLayout in Android, you can use constraints to position it relative to the parent layout. Here's an example XML layout code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Other views in the layout -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bottom Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

By using these constraints, the button will stay fixed at the bottom of the layout, regardless of the size or position of other views within the ConstraintLayout.

Comment: This answer was likely generated by blindly pasting the question into [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) and blindly pasting the output into the answer box, without ***any*** understanding of the answer or if it actually (correctly) answers the question.